# React Native: Context not passed on Navigator scene change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm using the [react-redux-provide](https://github.com/loggur/react-redux-provide) library, which passes a store state between my decorated components using React's `context`.

On scene change, that `context` is lost, causing the `react-redux-provide` library to reset the stores rather than access their updated state.

I'm struggling with debugging the issue properly and could use some help figuring out what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with my usage of `react-redux-provide`. I wasn't decorating my router component with `@provide`, which makes `context` accessible by child components.